# PHP CURL with HTTP2 not enabled

Tags: php, apache, curl, http2

I have configured cURL, PHP on AWS server like this.

```
[root@ip-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ~]# curl -V
curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1k zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.6.2 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.4.2 nghttp2/1.27.0-DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets PSL 

[root@ip-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ~]# php -v
PHP 7.0.21 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2017 15:46:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

[root@ip-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ~]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon)
Server built:   Sep 15 2017 22:56:01
```

I have cURL with HTTP2 supported but I am using cURL with HTTP2 in PHP. It is not working and gave me an error: `"Unexpected HTTP/1.x request"`

[PHP WITH CURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6mth.png)
[CURL SUPPORTS HTTP2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB2lC.png)

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information regarding this issue.

Comment: The [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html) do say *libcurl uses this 3rd party library for the low level protocol handling parts. The reason for this is that HTTP/2 is much more complex at that layer than HTTP/1.1 (which we implement on our own) and that nghttp2 is an already existing and well functional library.*

Comment: the version of curl installed may not correlate with the version of libcurl used by php, run `phpinfo(~0);` and check the curl section

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
cURL supports HTTP2 but PHP-CURL is not supported HTTP2 protocol.

Comment: @hanshenrik

I have the same version of cURL and libcURL 7.51.0

I have attached images for this.

Comment: bet it has something to do with the ssl backend, in your setup, php's libcurl is compiled with libnss as the ssl backend, while your cli curl is compiled with OpenSSL as the ssl backend. try to recompile php-curl with OpenSSL too?